# Creating a custom task scheduler in Adobe CQ

Tags: quartz-scheduler, aem, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, sling

1. We have a specific requirement to create a custom scheduler in CQ to perform some admnistrative tasks based on some parameters specified by the administrator. I have seen the Scheduler service offered by Sling. But wanted to know whether there is any issues in using Quratz APIs direcly rather than using this sling wrapper to schedule the tasks? Wanted to know did any one us alredy has developed such a CQ Component?
2. Is there any issue in invoking CQ flush agent programatically (as a scheduled Job, which runs periodically based on some configurations)?

Any pointers in this area would help us a lot.
Thanks,

San

Comment: #2, There is no issue to flush cache programatically.  you can also write a servlet to flush cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Schedulers in CQ are working well. I programmed many in my years as a CQ developer. It is an OSGi service either implementing the `java.lang.Runnable` or `org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.Job`. The former is usually enough. You only have to configure the `scheduler.expression` property which follows the quartz syntax and implement the `run` method.
2. I can't answer that as I never tried it. But I don't see why it shouldn't work. At my customer we have an independent cron job deleting the dispatcher cache instead of using a flush agent.